# Why it is not possible to access pointer in linked list like this?

Tags: c, linked-list

I declared node as follows,

```
typedef struct slinkedlist {
    int data;
    struct slinedlist *next;
} node;
```

I have temp pointer `node * tmp` in my code, why can't I access `tmp->next->next`.

/* Added code */

```
   typedef struct slinkedlist {
        int data;
        struct slinedlist *next;
    } node;


    node *start;

/* Assume I have 5 nodes in a list */

    void ex(void)
    {
        node *tmp;

        tmp = start->next->next; /* This will be error in C , explain me, why? */

        /* But this works fine */
        tmp = start->next;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
```

why i will get error if i access start->next->next?

Comment: What happens when you try?  Do you get an error message?  What?

Comment: This way you are in danger of null-pointer dereferencing.

Comment: You allocated memory for the pointer not for the struct

Comment: Why do you think that it is not possible? If you can ensure that the pointers are valid, you can access pointers like that. But it is not advisable.

Comment: We need more context information, possibly a [mcve]. Otherwise your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo: `slinedlist` -> `slinkedlist` ?

Comment: If we could actually see some code, it would help alot.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as tmp points to the last node, tmp->next will be null such that tmp->next->next will cause a null pointer dereferencing.

Comment: Just to clarify... by error, do you mean segmentation fault? Anyway, since both tmp=start->next->next; and tmp=start->next; tmp=tmp->next; are logically the same, there is only one last explanation I could think of: the compiler optimizes the former resulting to an out of order execution between the 1st and 2nd dereference.

Comment: One way to check if that is indeed the problem is to look at the assembly code generated. If the former resulted to a dereferencing that are close in succession, then an out of order execution will cause a seg fault. In that case, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: Having a tmp to hold the result of the 1st dereferencing would result to dereferencing assembly instructions that are further apart which would ensure that the 1st one is already done before the 2nd one is attempted.